# Angular- how to automatically display value in drop down on page load

Tags: angular

I'm working on an Angular application, and on one of the pages is a form with two drop downs displaying a date (day & month in the first one, year in the second one).

Apparently this form used to automatically display the date entered for the selected record when the page loaded, but has recently stopped doing this. I have only recently started working for this company, so have no prior knowledge of how/ when this was working correctly.

In the HTML, the drop downs are displayed with:

```
<label for="provisionalDate" class="dropdown-label">
    Provisional Date:
    <select class="form-control" id="provisionalDate" name="provisionalDate" [attr.disabled]="loadingPayers ? '' : null" [(ngModel)]="searchOptions.provisionalDate" (change)="provDateChanged($event)" [class.error]="provDateError">
        <option *ngFor="let provDate of provisionalDates" value="{{ provDate.ddmm }}">{{ provDate.label }}</option>
    </select>
</label>

<label for="provisionalDate" class="dropdown-label">
    <!-- Calendar Year: -->
    <select class="form-control" id="incomeYear" name="incomeYear" [attr.disabled]="loadingPayers ? '' : null" [(ngModel)]="searchOptions.incomeYear" (change)="provDateChanged($event)" [class.error]="provDateError">
        <option *ngFor="let incomeYear of incomeYears" value="{{ incomeYear }}">{{ incomeYear }}</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

The TypeScript function used to populate/ update these fields is defined in provisional-reminders.ts:

```
this.datesService.getJustNextProvisionalDate().subscribe(
    response => {
        this.nextProvisionalDate = response;
        const selectedProvDate = this.nextProvisionalDate.provisionalDateFormattedForQuery.split('-');
        this.searchOptions.provisionalDate = selectedProvDate[1] + '-' + selectedProvDate[2];
        this.searchOptions.incomeYear = selectedProvDate[0];
        console.log("selectedProvDate[0]: ", selectedProvDate[0]);
        this.provDatesLoaded = true;
        if (this.firmLoaded) {
            this.doProvSearch();
        } else {
            this.fallbackSearchTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                this.doProvSearch();
            }, 1000)
        }
        //console.log("this.nextProvisionalDate: ", this.nextProvisionalDate);
        //console.log("searchOptions.provisionalDate: ", this.searchOptions.provisionalDate);

        // firm subscription assumes searchOptions.provisionalDate is set, so it must be initialised after this
        if (this.firstload) {
            console.log("this.firstLoad: ", this.firstload);
            this.setSelectionSubscription();
            this.firstload = false;
        }
    },
    error => {
        const message = new Message();
        message.type = MessageType.ERROR;
        message.message = "An error occurred while retrieving the next provisional date.";
        this.messagingService.emitMessage(message);
    }
);
```

From the debug I've added, I can see in the console that all of the date variables have their values set correctly when the page loads, but for some reason, only the the `incomeYear` drop down is actually displaying a value automatically when first navigating to the page. Why isn't the `provisionalDate` field also automatically displaying a value? They both display the range of values I'm expecting when clicking the drop down, and I can select a value correctly, it's just that when the page first loads, the date field is blank, rather than displaying one of its options, but the year field displays one of its options.

When the page loads, the form is shown as:

[image: drop downs]

Why is it that the year automatically displays a value, but the day/month doesn't? If I click the drop down, I can see that the options have all been populated correctly:

[image: drop down populated]

The PHP function that's being used to retrieve the dates is:

```
public function getJustNextProvDate()
{
    $nextProvDate = DB::select("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [db].[date].[provisional] PT WHERE PT.provisionalDate > getdate() ORDER BY PT.provisionalDate")[0];

    $provisionalDate = explode('.', $nextProvDate->provisionalDate)[0];
    $date = Carbon::createFromFormat( "Y-m-d H:i:s", $provisionalDate );

    $return = [
        'provisionalDate' => $nextProvDate->provisionalDate,
        'provisionalDateFormatted' => $date->format('d/m/Y'),
        //'provisionalDateFormatted' => $date->format('d/m'),
        'provisionalDateFormattedForQuery' => $date->format('Y-m-d'),
    ];

    return response()->json($return);
}
```

**Edit**

An example of the data held by `searchOptions.provisionalDate` is:

> 29 10

An example of the data held by `selectedProvDate[1]` is:

> 10

An example of the data held by `selectedProvDate[2]` is:

> 29

i.e. the date values for day & month.

**Edit**

I've just spotted that there is the following block at the start of the start of the provisional-reminders.ts file:

```
public provisionalDates:any = [
    {"ddmm": "01-15", "label": "15 January" },
    {"ddmm": "01-28", "label": "28 January" },
    // etc
];
```

so it's clear that this is what's being used to format how the date is displayed.

Comment: Can you post the data for searchOptions, provisionalDates adn incomeYears.. Seems to be some inconsistency in the data !

Comment: What do you mean? Post the data held by these variables?

Comment: Yes...Would you be able to create a stackblitz recreating the problem ?? https://stackblitz.com Here ...

Comment: The variables you asked for hold the various `date` variable data, i.e. `searchOptions` holds a number of options used for searching the database- one of these options is the date, `provisionalDates` holds a list of dates (dd mm) & `incomeYears` holds a list of years...

Comment: Its very difficult to answer without an example even though it sounds simpple. Would suggest you to take some time and recreate the problem in stackblitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the **incomeYear** is displaying properly is, Your ngModel **searchOptions.incomeYear**  has the value(2018) available in the **incomeYears** JSON that you used to display the income year drop-down.

```
<option *ngFor="let incomeYear of incomeYears" value="{{ incomeYear }}">{{ incomeYear }}</option>
```

You need to verify your **provisionalDates** JSON which value **(provDate.ddmm)** has any value similar to your ngModel **searchOptions.provisionalDate** value.

```
 <option *ngFor="let provDate of provisionalDates" value="{{ provDate.ddmm }}">{{ provDate.label }}</option>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, as I understand, you're saying the problem is a formatting issue? How would I verify that `provisionalDates` has a value similar to `provDate.ddmm`?

Comment: Can you console and share the incomeyear, provisionalDates and selectedProvDate JSON.

Comment: In the `getJustNextProvisionalDates()` Angular function, `incomeYears` gives: "(2) [2019, 2018]", `searchOptions.provisionalDate` gives: "10-29", & `this.nextProvisionalDate` gives: "{provisionalDate: "2018-10-29 00:00:00", provisionalDateFormatted: "29/10/2018", provisionalDateFormattedForQuery: "2018-10-29"}"

Comment: So I can see that the variable has a value, it's just that the field in the form doesn't seem to actually display that value when the page loads...

Comment: If your  **provisionalDates:any**  harcoded.Please check if you have the {"ddmm": "10-29", "label": "29 October" }.